# No se reciben los parametros correctos en la funcion de getServerSideProps en next js

Tags: typescript, next.js, bug

Tengo un proyecto de next js 13 con typescript y estoy usando TRPC, en una parte de mi web genero etiquetas Link con esta url {`/app/profile/show/topic/${idOwner}/${emailOwner}/${element.Id}`}, esa pagina a la cual se van a dirigir usa getServerSideProps y recibo esos 3 parametros, aqui es donde me surge el siguiente problema: cuando visitan la pagina la funcion de getServerSideProps por alguna razón se ejecuta dos veces **(lo cual según yo no debería ser ya que es una función para el servidor y tengo otras funciones así y solo se ejecutan una vez)** ahora en la primera llamada recibe los parámetros correctamente (idOwner, emailOwner, element.id) y la lógica siguiente es correcta, pero en la segunda llamada por alguna extraña razón el ultimo parámetro (element.id) lo recibe con valor de 'none' (esa palabra la estoy usando en varias partes del proyecto para poner estados iniciales como 'ninguno', la palabra si es cosa mía no que mande un error o algo next como advertencia y ponga eso) y por consiguiente me salta el error en terminal y consola, pondré el código

```
export async function getServerSideProps(
context: GetServerSidePropsContext
) {
try {
    //usando TRPC
    const helpers = createServerSideHelpers({
        router: appRouter,
        ctx: {
            db: new DataBase(),
            sender: new Sender(),
            token: context.req.cookies.tokenSession
        },
        transformer: superjson
    });
    
    const idUser = context.params?.idUser as string;
    const email = context.params?.email as string;
    //este es el parametro que en la segunda llamada me da diferente
    const idTopic = context.params?.idTopic as string;

    const data = await helpers.user.getOneTopic.fetch({ idUser, idTopic, email, });

    return {
        props: {
            trpcState: helpers.dehydrate(),
            //omito todo lo que devuelvo para no alargar el codigo
        }
    }

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return undefined;
}
```

la primera vez que se ejecuta la función todo es correcto y de echo se muestra correctamente bien en la pagina pero como se llama instantáneamente la segunda, me da el error, no afecta dentro de la experiencia de usuario o inconsistencias en la información y demás pero igual no quiero dejar ese error descontrolado, alguna idea de que este pasando?, inclusive si paso los 3 parámetros en los props y los imprimo ahora en el cliente son correctos por la primera vez que se ejecuta en el servidor, he intentado validar que no se pidan las cosas si es 'none' y demás pero tampoco funciona